# CKEditor content field is readonly even though it should be editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I have a web application that uses CKEditor version 4.4.7 with angular js and MVC.Net.
Sometimes the content field of the editor opens as readonly even though I set the readonly option field to false. This only happens in IE10 where I can see that the resulting HTML body element of the CKEditor has attribute contenteditable="false".

Does anyone have any idea of why it is set and maybe indicate which part of my code sets that?

Thank you
Jeeji

Comment: "which part of my code"? So, where is your code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I did not implement this feature in our code, so I was thinking if anyone could give examples of which code has possibility of setting contenteditable="false" or which code cause contenteditable to be false.

Comment: So instead of showing us an example with that problem, you want us to list every possible way that the editor can be disabled?

Comment: I thought that there might be some FEW common ways of disabling the editor, which might be a common cause for my problem.